# Angularjs:Crawling a site

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, web-crawler, bots

I have made an angular app with rails as a backend.I have read lots of blog and articles about how to make an angulajs app crawlable.

for example - :  "http://www.example.com/#!/home" Google bots will convert this url into "http://www.example.com/?_escape_fragment_=/home".

I have written logic that wherever request comes with "?_escape_fragement_=" format ,I just returns the json data in html file.

for example-:

```
 <p>name: test</p>
 <p>designation :test1</p>
```

so i just want to know that this much is enough for making an ajax application crawlable.if not then please suggest me the other ways to make an application crawlable.

Thanks,

Comment: I suspect you read http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html ?

Comment: @Florian :- suppose my orginal ajax page for example: "http://www.example.com/#!/home" contains on anchor tag <a href=#!test></a>.Then do i need to add the same anchor tag <a href=#!test></a> in a page for the request "http://www.example.com/?escape_fragment_=/home".

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating HTML snapshots from your existing codebase rather than adding further complexity for creating pages. [Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot) (see option 3) recommends using a headless browser to [prerender](http://prerender.io) your AJAX application before returning to the client.

You can also see some significant performance improvements by prerendering for all users and initialising your Angular app in its current state - especially in hybrid apps/mobile websites - this reduces XHR requests and painting in the browser. More on this here;

https://github.com/ithkuil/angular-on-server/wiki/Running-AngularJS-on-the-server-with-Node.js-and-jsdom